# javascript function to insert values from content-editable span to a hidden form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to fetch values from editable spans for hidden form to a hidden form via this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillup() {
        document.getElementById('fname').value = document.getElementById('nfname').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('mname').value = document.getElementById('nmname').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('lname').value = document.getElementById('nlname').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('email').value = document.getElementById('nemail').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('gen').value = document.getElementById('ngen').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('dob').value = document.getElementById('ndob').innerHTML;
        var str = document.getElementById('nloc').innerHTML;
        var parts = str.split(',');
        document.getElementById('city').value = parts[0];
        document.getElementById('state').value = parts[1];
        if(document.getElementById('fname').value == '' || document.getElementById('mname').value == '' || document.getElementById('lname').value == '' || document.getElementById('email').value == '' || document.getElementById('gen').value == '' || document.getElementById('dob').value == '' || document.getElementById('city').value == '' || document.getElementById('state') == '' ){
            alert('something is empty!');
        }
        else {
            alert(str);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and following is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('admin_update') }}">
        <div class="hidden">
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
            <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" />
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
            <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" />
            <input type="text" id="gen" name="gen" />
            <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" />
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
            <input type="text" id="state" name="state" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="save changes" onclick="fillup()" />
    </form>
```

as said earlier, except the submit button other textareas are disabled in the form, the spans are:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="fname">
            <span class="fname" id="nfname" contenteditable="true" onchange="appear()">{{ fname }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">First name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mname">
            <span class="mname" id="nmname" contenteditable="true" onchange="appear()">{{ mname }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">Middle name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="lname">
            <span class="lname" id="nlname" contenteditable="true" onchange="appear()">{{ lname }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">Last name</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="email">
            <span class="email" id="nemail" contenteditable="true">{{ email }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">Email</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gender">
            <span class="gender" id="ngen" contenteditable="true">{{ gen }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">Gender</span>
        </div>
        <div class="DOB">
            <span class="DOB" id="ndob" contenteditable="true" id="datepicker">{{ dob|date("m/d/Y") }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">Date of birth</span>
        </div>
        <div class="loc">
            <span class="loc" id="nloc" contenteditable="false">{{ loc }}</span>
            <hr />
            <span class="st">Location</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: "*sorry for a little messy code here, but it is very urgent*" If it's so urgent, maybe you should hire somebody lol. Take the time to clearly state what your issue is, what you've done so far, what errors you're seeing/experiencing, what the expected outcome of your code is, etc. 'Cause I don't know what you're asking here.

Comment: I am really sorry for that, actually what happening here that the input fields are not receiving the values from the span tags, I think the onclick event is ignoring the javascript function

Comment: "*I think the onclick event is ignoring the javascript function*" You *think*, or it *is*, ignoring the function? Are you getting any of the `alert()`'s to fire in your function? What is happening when you click the `submit` button? Ie. the page reloads/form is sent? Nothing happens? Javascript error?

Comment: nothing is coming up, actually, i am sure that its ignoring the js, but i do not find any reason to why

Comment: and I know its going to be a silly mistake but I have just learned and started using the javascript

Comment: @Marcus Please help if you are there

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put your code into a plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/n8m58L7dFiFOPJBKJfvI?p=preview

To me it looks ok - and it definitly works, as far as I understand your requirement.
I would suggest to bind the function call "fillup()" to the onSubmit event of the form.

```
<form method="post" action="." onSubmit="fillup()">
```

Also please check for this line in the function:

```
document.getElementById('email').value = document.getElementById('nemail').innerHTML;
```

The element's id is NOT "email" - it is "mail"